# Spring boot connect AWS java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, networking

Our server need to use AWS S3 to store users images, our server is springboot ,we will connect S3 to upload image, sometimes it raise exception :java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused, once the exception was raised, it will alway rasie utils we restart springboot service .
It can work fine in some days (1 ~2) and then raise Connection refused

```
  String fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
  String contentType = WUtils.getContentType(fileExt);

  AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                    aws_access_key_id,
                    aws_secret_key);
            Region region = Region.AP_EAST_1;
            presigner = S3Presigner.builder()
                    .region(region)
                    .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
                    .build();

            PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(bucketFolderName + "/" + fileName)
                    .contentType(contentType)
                    .build();

            PutObjectPresignRequest presignRequest = PutObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                    .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                    .putObjectRequest(objectRequest)
                    .build();

            PresignedPutObjectRequest presignedRequest = presigner.presignPutObject(presignRequest);

            // Upload content to the Amazon S3 bucket by using this URL.
            URL url = presignedRequest.url();

            // Create the connection and use it to upload the new object by using the presigned URL.
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            connection.getOutputStream().write(pic);
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                imagePath = url.toString().replace("?" + url.getQuery(), "");
                log.info("======Upload Image Url:" + imagePath);
            } else {
                log.error("======Upload Image fail, responseCode:" + responseCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(String.format("Module:%s,Method:%s,Info:%s", "File Upload", "generatePresignedUrlUploadImage", e.getMessage()));
        } finally {
            if (presigner != null) {
                presigner.close();
            }
            return imagePath;
        }
 

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:557)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:555)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:554)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:598)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:198)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1263)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:175)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:220)
    at com.wealth.api.service.AmazonService.generatePresignedUrlUploadImage(AmazonService.java:357)
    at com.wealth.api.service.AmazonService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$23d39f70.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.wealth.api.service.AmazonService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$58fed417.generatePresignedUrlUploadImage(<generated>)
    at com.wealth.api.controller.CommControl.uploadFile(CommControl.java:294)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor943.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

AWS support can not resolve this issue ,it suggests retry... but once the exception was raised, retry will be useless util we restart springboot.

===========================================================
AWS support had captured the network packets, no issues were found.

Comment: you can increase idle time and connection time of aws connection. and also check here : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-resolve-ssh-connection-errors/

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to upload an object via S3Presigner as opposed to the S3Client object's putObject method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **Spring BOOT app** to upload assets to an Amazon S3 bucket, look at using the **S3Client** object's **putObject** method as opposed **S3Presigner**.

**S3Presigner** is for apps without requiring authentication. Your Spring BOOT app has access to creds (shown in your code).

More information about this subject here:

[Working with Amazon S3 presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html)

Another newer way when using the **AWS SDK for Java V2** is to use [Transfer Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html)  for accelerated file transfers. A Java code example is shown here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/transfermanager/UploadObject.java

Answer (score 0):

I had uploaded the image using S3Client, but the code can not work, It can upload image successfully but the program was hold in **"upload.completionFuture().join();" method**...

```
String imagePath = "";
    S3TransferManager transferManager = null;
        String fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String contentType = WUtils.getContentType(fileExt);

        AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                aws_access_key_id_for_upload_image,
                aws_secret_key_for_upload_image);
        Region region = Region.AP_EAST_1;
        transferManager = S3TransferManager.builder()
                .s3ClientConfiguration(cfg ->cfg.region(region)             .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
                        .targetThroughputInGbps(20.0)
                        .minimumPartSizeInBytes(10 * 1024L))
                .build();

        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(w_file.getInputStream(), file);

        log.info("======upload image begin,{}", fileName);
        FileUpload upload =
                transferManager.uploadFile(u -> u.source(file)
                        .putObjectRequest(p -> p.bucket(bucketName).key(bucketFolderName + "/" + fileName)));
        
        // upload...
        upload.completionFuture().join();//<---Hold ....
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).